# Infinite Scroll + Isotope + Firebase Firestore to achieve Pagination

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-firestore, infinite-scroll, jquery-isotope

New to web development. Thanks in advance!

I am trying to display items stored in Firestore by calling paginate queries. The goal is that every time when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, we call Firestore, retrieve more items, and display them.

I have found that Infinite Scroll (https://infinite-scroll.com/) and Isotope (https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) may be helpful, yet have been trying for a while and couldn't figure it out.

Currently, what I have is:

```
  var itemCollection = []
  recipeRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    var lastVisible = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1]
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      itemCollection.push(doc.data());
    })
    return res.render('user', {...})})
```

I may have to trigger an event to read more items in Firestore then push results to the array and display. Yet I only found the example code below.

This sample code seems to have a "preloaded" page with no need to query from a database, then just append that page as an object of Isotope. In my case, what I have is an array and I do need to read Firestore, so not very sure how to do it. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

```
// with Isotope & jQuery
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  // Isotope options...
  itemSelector: '.grid__item', 
});

// get Isotope instance
var iso = $grid.data('isotope');

// init Infinite Scroll
$grid.infiniteScroll({
  // Infinite Scroll options...
  append: '.grid__item',
  outlayer: iso,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

firestore supports orerBy and StartAfter, You can keep the last document and request next query with that document

```
let lastDoc=null
db.collection('collectionName').orderBy('orderingKey').limit(10).get()
.then(docs=>{
    const data = docs.map(doc=>doc.data());
    lastDoc = data[data.length-1]
})
```

to paginate

```
db.collection('collectionName').orderBy('orderingKey').startAfter(lastDoc)
.limit(10).get()
.then(docs=>{
    const data = docs.map(doc=>doc.data());
    lastDoc = data[data.length-1]
})
```